# CSS sibling structure if-then

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

Hope you can help me with this CSS trick.

Basically what I need is this kind of CSS

```
if 'container' has sibling 'mySibling' {
    #myDiv{
    }
}
if 'container' has no sibling {
    #myDiv{
    }   
}
```

For this HTML

```
<div id="mySibling"></div>
<div id="container">    
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

sibling sometimes will not be present, and I need different css for myDiv in these cases

Any help would be appreciated, I tried doing + and ~ selectors but I don't think I have proper logic.

Comment: So... you want CSS media queries? Or you want JavaScript? Your question is a little vague.

Comment: Do you mean 'if container has CHILD' ? container doesn't have any siblings

Comment: I think I need CSS media queries, but I suppose JS would work also, but I prefer pure CSS

Comment: @BrianGlaz sorry I ment sibling, let me fix the HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#mySibling + #container #myDiv {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzq3S/

Note, I've changed the `id`s to `classes` in the fiddle just to show the two sets of `div` elements, but you get the idea...

This breaks down to `myDiv` that is a child of `container` that is a sibling of `mySibling`.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much, I figured it had to do with '+' but I had the incorrect structure, I was putting 'mySibling' after the 'containter', Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your html is correct; in your example, you forgot to specify whether you're using an id or a class! Possible options for your html:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="mySibling"></div>  
   <div class="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="mySibling"></div>  
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

For the sake of your example, we'll use id's, even though [some would say it's better practice to use classes](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)

Now for the CSS.

The + and ~ selectors operate in slightly different ways. The + selects *adjacent* siblings, while the ~ selects *all* siblings. Because CSS doesn't handle logic quite the same way as actual programming languages, you can't check to see if a container holds a certain element before applying styles, but you can use the sibling selectors to style elements that are next to certain other elements.

My suggestion:

```
.container #myDiv {
  /* Your styles for #myDiv */
}
.container #mySibling + #myDiv {
  /* Your styles for #myDiv it is next to #mySibling. 
     Will override the styles a */
}
```

You can check out an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8r2TZ/. Note, I specified "myDiv" as a class, because I used it more than once, and my CSS reflects that.

Comment: Both sibling selectors only look at following siblings, so `~` won't really match *all* of them.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed up my HTML and in the production code I am using classes. Note that the HTML you show is not the structure in my case. Take another look if your interested.

Comment: Oh that's changed from what I saw. In that case, Dryden Long's answer is the best :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to have a CSS rule for each case without relying on overriding, it's still possible, since there's a selector for elements with no siblings:

```
#mySibling + #container > #myDiv {
}

#container:only-child > #myDiv {
}
```

(You can even achieve compatibility with old IEs by using `:first-child` in lieu of `:only-child` since `#mySibling` comes first.)

Comment: Thanks this helps for the specific case of only-child, but in the production code some other children can exist, the case I needed was with the specific sibling above "myDiv". The selected answer seems to work in my case.